# setting longer delay between testimonial slider

Tags: jquery

We are using JS to make a testimonial slider. I need the pause between slides to be longer. So people get the chance to read the text, but going round in circles.

Any help appreciated.

The js is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var slider = function() {
    $('#testimonials .slide').filter(':visible').fadeOut(1000,function(){
        if($(this).next('li.slide').size()){
            $(this).next().fadeIn(2000);
        }
        else{
            $('#testimonials .slide').eq(0).fadeIn(1000);
        }
    });
};
var interval = setInterval(slider, 5000);
$('#testimonials .slide').hover(function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
}, function() {
    interval = setInterval(slider, 5000);
});
```

});

html is:

> some message here

> some message here

css is:

```
#testimonials {width: 500px;height: 100px;list-style-type: none !important;}
#testimonials .slide {list-style-type: none !important;}
blockquote {font-size: 18px;font-family:"proxima-nova-1","proxima-nova-2", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color: #333;font-style: italic; line-height:24px;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the line...

```
interval = setInterval(slider, 5000);
```

...change the `5000` to a larger number. `1000` is roughly `1` second.

Comment: perfect thanks, I set to 5000 because that should be 5 seconds, but seemingly it isnt.. perhaps its a cache issue, or the interval wasnt flushed , I dont know, but set to 8000 and all is now fine. Cheers @alex